# return and add to database

Tags: php, mysql

I have tried to make the following code. I want to add date, day, fromtime, totime into my database. But when I choose the values in my forms, I dont get anything registred in my database. It is connected succesful to mysql.

The code is here:

```
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>

    <form method="post">
        <h3>Add your worktime to database</h3><br>
            <input type="date" name="date"><br><br>
            <input type="text" name="day"><br>
            <input type="time" name="fromtime">
            <input type="time" name="totime">
            <input type="submit" value="submit"><br><br>
    </form>


</body>

<?php
$username = "root";
$password = "root";
$hostname = "127.0.0.1:3306"; 

//connection to the database
$dbhandle = mysql_connect($hostname, $username, $password) 
 or die("Unable to connect to MySQL");
echo "Connected to MySQL<br><br>";

//select a database to work with
$selected = mysql_select_db("danskebank",$dbhandle) 
  or die("Could not select examples");

$date = $_POST['date'];
$day = $_POST['day'];
$fromtime = $_POST['fromtime'];
$totime = $_POST['totime'];

$sql = "INSERT INTO addWorkTime(date, day, fromtime, totime) VALUES('$date', '$day', '$fromtime', 'totime')";


//execute the SQL query and return records
$result = mysql_query("SELECT date, day, fromtime, totime FROM addWorkTime");

//fetch tha data from the database 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
   Print"<h3>Return from database:</h3>";
   echo "Date: ".$row{'date'}."<br>"."Day: ".$row{'day'}."<br>"."From Time: ".$row{'fromtime'}."<br>"."To Time: ".$row{'totime'}; //display the results
}


?>

</html>
```

[image: Database Structure]

I hope somebody can help me?

Best Regards Mads

Comment: I don't feel like you are executing your insert

Comment: And your code is open to SQL injection...You should escape variables before inserting into database.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answers. I just have to read up on the SQL injection, before I post the correct code :-/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RoyalBG is correct, you need to have the line `$result = mysql_query($sql);` in your code at the correct point to actually run your insert line.  Also you should read up on SQL Injection because your code as you've written it currently is extremely vulnerable to SQL Injection.